# VIEW MySQL UNION BIT field

Tags: mysql, view

У меня есть задача создать MySQL VIEW путем обеднения двух таблиц с помощью UNION, причем две таблицы имеют как общие поля так и разные.
к примеру в таблице 1 есть поле типа BIT во второй таблице данного поля данного типа нет но в виде оно должно присутствовать, можно в обеднение сделать так
битовое_поле ...... UNION .... 0 AS битовое поле 
но в результате в виде при сведении данное поле будет отображаться не как битовое а как числовое. Как правильно свести поля?

Answer (score 0):

```
-- есть field1, есть field2,     нет field3
SELECT  field1,      field2, null as field3 from table1 
UNION ALL
-- есть field1,  нет field2,    есть field3
SELECT  field1,        null,         field3 from table1
```

Если не нравится NULL - то любой литерал (ноль, пустая строка, любое другое значение).